# Network monitor for webdeveloper

Tags: network-monitoring, google-chrome-devtools

When using Google chrome there is a handy network monitor tool. However the chrome network tool only keeps track of the current open webpage.

There are a lot of complicated network monitor tools available and I only need the features of the chrome network monitor tool.

To keep track of all the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE etc.) activity I am searching for a tool that has the same idea and interface as the chrome network tool.

Someone knows a tool like that?

Some screenshots with the wished features:

**A overview of all the files downloaded**
[image: A overview of all the network activity]

**when selecting a file you can nicely see the headers**
[image: header]

**And with the tab response the content of the body is visible**
[image: content]

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot of the Chrome network monitor, so I will know what to look for? And if it's an extension, please provide a link to the extension's page at the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Its standard in all chrome browsers you can see when right click -> inspect -> network. I shall upload a screenshot as you asked.

Comment: Great, I just don't have chrome installed, so I will wait for the screenshot.

Comment: OK, Now I see the screenshots. However, this is a developer tool, which is only available in chrome (and similar tools in other browsers). I find that hard to believe there is some kind of webpage inspection tool like this one which will apply to all ongoing traffic.
But I will still I will do some investigation about this. if I will find something I'll write an answer ASAP.

Comment: `However the chrome network tool only keeps track of the current open webpage` - Actually, on the bottom bar, see that solid circle?  Click on it, and the network activity is kept between webpages.

Comment: @lzkata I know that but still it only records the traffic in that tab and not of all current tabs. I now use fiddler2, it looks almost the same but it does what I want. But still thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try Fiddler from http://fiddler2.com/

I use that for web development and especially find it handy that it allows you to modify and replay a previously recorded http request.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're interested in HTTP headers and content but for all traffic.  Though it's a more complex tool, Wireshark can easily provide what you're looking for, despite it's initially intimidating layout and wealth of capabilities.

1. Run wireshark
2. Select the adapter which will be communicating (ie. your internet adapter) and begin capture
3. In the "Filter:" field, type "http.request" (sans quotes) and press Apply

The resulting output will contain each request made by your system (this is potentially more than just your browser session: you may prefer to further filter the traffic by adding "&& ip.addr==" to the filter if you're getting too much traffic in your output).  If you only know the server's name, you can use "nslookup .com" in a command line to resolve the server's IP address.

When you click a request in the top frame of Wireshark, the middle frame will present the layers within.  Expand the "Hypertext Transfer Protocol" layer by pressing the + next to it to expose the headers for the request.

Finally, if you're interested in viewing the response headers or content, right click on the request of interest in the top frame and click "Follow TCP Stream".

NOTE: All of the above assumes you're not trying to capture traffic to a webserver hosting on localhost, 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). It's free and avalible for Windows, Linux & Mac. Looks very similar to Chromes dev tools in my opinion.

Comment: this tool is more a Firefox plug in and not free. Its a 30 day trial!

Comment: Right, I didn't noticed.